# How to navigate to a child route from root?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am have a angular project that there is a component for tab. Now I am trying to use a menu to navigate to each tabs directly.

main-tab.component.html

```
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar mat-align-tabs="center">
    <a
        mat-tab-link
        *ngFor="let link of navLinks"
        [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { Content: [link.path] } }]"
        routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive"
        [active]="rla.isActive">
        {{link.label}}
    </a>
</nav>
<router-outlet name="Content"></router-outlet>
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/(container:home)', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, outlet: 'container'},
  {
    path: 'Abc',
    component: AbcComponent,
    outlet: 'container',
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: '/(container:Abc/(Content:Link1))', pathMatch: 'full'},
      { path: 'Link1', component: Link1, outlet: 'Content'},
      { path: 'Link2', component: Link2, outlet: 'Content'},
      { path: 'Link3', component: Link3, outlet: 'Content'},
      { path: 'Link4', component: Link4, outlet: 'Content'}
    ]
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/(container:home)', pathMatch: 'full'},
];
```

The above are actually something from the example of Angular material so there is no issue. The problem is that when I try to add the following menu (which is from a button on the header), it cannot navigate.

menu.component.html

```
<mat-menu #Menu="matMenu">
    <button mat-menu-item *ngFor="let link of navLinks" [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { Content: [link.path] } }]">{{link.label}}</button> 
</mat-menu>
```

Is there a way to navigate to the Link2/3/4 directly outside of the tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am right, you are trying to access Link1/Link2 which are child routes of Abc.

If yes you would have to first get onto ABC and then get onto child components.

You can not access : localhost:/Link1 directly.

You can access like localhost:/Abc/Link1 only.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You are right. So what I am asking is how to use routerLink in menu.component.html to access localhost/(container:Abc/(Content:Link2/3/4)) without getting into localhost/(container:Abc) first

Comment: I think you can use something like this in theHomeComponent 

ngOnInit() {

router.navigate(['Abc/ContentLin:{Link1/Link2}']);

}

otherwise you can user [routerLink] = "Abc/Link1". In case this isn't helping can you provide a stackblitz link for your code so that I can review and help